# Value of C_INT32_T negative in Intel Visual Fortran

Tags: windows, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

While attempting to use fftw3 libraries in VS2008 with Intel Fortran, I encountered a problem with the data types defined by the iso_c_binding.

Considering that fftw3 defines in  fftw3.f03:

```
  integer, parameter :: C_FFTW_R2R_KIND = C_INT32_T
```

When compiling a code with the line

```
      integer(C_FFTW_R2R_KIND), dimension(*), intent(in) :: kind
```

I get the following error:

```
error #6684: This is an incorrect value for a kind type parameter in this context.   [C_FFTW_R2R_KIND]
```

To understand the problem, I tried the following code

```
program test
implicit none
call sub()
contains
subroutine sub()
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  write(*,*) C_INT, C_DOUBLE , C_INT32_T,  C_INT_FAST32_T,  C_INT_LEAST32_T
end subroutine sub
end program test
```

After running, the following result is displayed:

```
4    8    -2     -2     -2
```

As -2 is not a valid data type, I assumed that was the problem and looking in https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678431, I replaced the line in fftw3.f03 by this:

```
  integer, parameter :: C_FFTW_R2R_KIND = 4 !C_INT32_T
```

And I can run the program without errors.
If anybody could confirm that this alternative is correct or how to solve the original problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: `-2` means that the C compiler doesn't define the particular type.  That may or may not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will work fine for Intel Fortran, although using `SELECTED_INT_KIND(8)` instead of 4 would be safer and more portable.

Intel Visual Fortran apparently uses Visual C++ as a companion C compiler. And apparently a version that does not supports these C99 types yet. AFAIK Visual C++ is more oriented towards C++ than C and does not bring new C standard features too fast. They are supported in recent versions though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k.aspx

In my opinion it would be more useful for Intel Fortran to define the `c_` kind values anyway even if the C compiler does not define those constants, but maybe it is not completely standard conforming. But I think it would be a useful extension.

Comment: Thank you very much, using `SELECTED_INT_KIND(8)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a newer version of Intel Fortran. If you are using VS2008, you would be at most using version 14; the current version is 18 and your test program there produces the result:

```
   4           8           4           4           4
```

Comment: Indeed I have access to version 11 of the compiler. Thank you for the information.